# When web.config is created server gives 500 server error

Tags: wordpress, web-config, iis-7.5, web-hosting

I'm new to web hosting. I have IIS 7.5 server and some WordPress sites are installed on this. and they use pretty URLs with them and has rewrite rules in web.config file.

I tried to setup a new WordPress site and when site is created on IIS it does not seems to be having a web.config file inside the site root. So I manually created a one, and when it is created site gives 500 internal server error (even with blank web.config).

When web.config is removed home page gets loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The web.config is only really needed for URL re-writing.

Because you created a new site, the WordPress code that detects and generates the web.config file has not yet run.

To trigger it, login to admin dashboard, go to permalinks and just click save. This will generate the web.config file.

Comment: but why does it through an error"500 internal server error" when I place a blank web.config file.

Comment: I don't know why a blank one throws an error. Is there a technical requirement on you needing to have a blank file?

Comment: No, I tried to add rewrite rules and got 500 error. So I tried a blank one.

Answer (score 0):

web.config file contains some configuration information....This file will be generated after seeting up dll's(In case of plugin configuration)..once we hit the url for the first time it will be generated in domain home...

So if you place a blank file...it doesn't have any information..so you're getting 500 error.